# In Latex, I want my caption to be lower relative to my figure. How do I do that?

Tags: spacing, captions

**instead of:**

[image]

```
   Figure 1
```

**I want:**

[image]

```
   --------

   Figure 1
```

**How do I manipulate this?**

Comment: Package `captino` does a good job here. `\captionsetup[figure]{aboveskip=20pt}` should do the job.

Comment: Just in case you're confused about the name of the package: it's `caption`, not `captino`. :-)

Comment: Sorry, i made a typo :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `caption` package and its `skip` key.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \captionsetup{skip=2cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Some picture here}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you want this to happen to all figures then put

```
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=2cm}
```

before `\begin{document}`

[image]

You can control the space above and below of caption separately by `aboveskip` and `belowskip` respectively.